Bilinear forms on abelian $p$-groups: Images of weak metabolizers in the Frattini quotient
Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group for $p$ an odd prime and $b : G \times G \to \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ is a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form.  A subgroup $H \leq G$ is a weak metabolizer for $b$ when $H^\perp = H$.  Consider the Frattini quotient $\bar{G} = G/(pG)$ and let $\bar{H}$ be the image of a weak metabolizer $H$ in $\bar{G}$.  My question is must $\dim \bar{H} \leq \frac{1}{2} \dim \bar{G}$ as $\mathbf{F}_p$-vector spaces?
Note: If $G$ is elementary so that $\bar{G} = G$, then the answer is yes as $H^\perp = H$ implies $2 \dim H = \dim G$.  The possible forms $b$ themselves are classified in Section 5 of Wall's 1963 paper Quadratic forms on finite groups, and related topics, but I have been unable to find a description of all possible weak metabolizers.
Motivation: I am really interested in the Casson–Gordon setup in low-dimensional topology, where $Y$ is a rational homology 3-sphere bounding a rational homology 4-ball $W$, $G = H_1(Y; \mathbf{Z})_{(p)}$ and the weak metabolizer is the kernel of the map to $H_1(W; \mathbf{Z})_{(p)}$.

Yes. We don't need the assumption that $p$ is odd or $b$ is symmetric.
Nondegeneracy means that the natural map $G \to G^\vee$ is an isomorphism. $H^\perp$ is the inverse image of $(G/H)^\vee$ under this map so $H= H^\perp$ implies that $H$ is the inverse image of $(G/H)^\vee$. In particular, the $p$-rank of $H$ equals the $p$-rank of $(G/H)^\vee$ which equals the $p$-rank of $G/H$ which is
$$\dim (G/H)/p(G/H) = \dim  \overline{G}/\overline{H} = \dim {\overline{G} } - \dim \overline{H}$$ so $$ \operatorname{rank} H+ \dim \overline{H} =\dim \overline{G}$$ but clearly $$ \dim \overline{H} \leq \operatorname{rank} H$$ so $$2\dim \overline{H} \leq \overline{G}$$ as desired.

Ha! You beat me to it. I was typing out basically the same answer, attracted by the bounty points, when yours appeared.

@Will For a group N, does N^v mean Hom(N, Q/Z)?

@NathanDunfield Yes, that's what I mean.

@WillSawin Thanks!  Assuming that \bar{N} is N/pN as in the question, why is dim(bar{G/H}) = dim(bar{G}) - dim(bar{H})?  If I take G = Z/(p^2 Z) and H =  the unique subgroup of order p, it seems like all of bar{G/H}, bar{G}, and bar{H} are Z/pZ and hence have dim = 1.

@NathanDunfield In the question you did not define $\bar{N}$ to be $N/pN$ but rather defined $\bar{H}$ to be the image of $H$ in $G/pG$. By that definition, $\bar{H}$ is trivial in your example.

@WillSawin Ah, you're right, not sure what I was thinking.  Regardless, many thanks for answering this!
